# Not able to find the Adobe Magento Commerce Developer Professional(AD0-E702)

Tags: magento2, certification

I was trying to schedule the certification exam for Adobe Magento Commerce Developer Professional but I am not able to find this exam in the list in Adobe Credential Manager.

If anyone have some idea about this, please guide me because when I have purchased the exam voucher, the mail says I can take this exam AD0-E702.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Please contact adobe@xvoucher.com and please ask your question and query there. They will reply to your email.***

You are correct, when Adobe retired their exam AD0-E702 they configured exam AD0-E711 as the replacement.

> **Check this :**

1. https://prnt.sc/Nug_RcX-psvy
2. https://prnt.sc/ITYLh5W65yRD

I have the same problem, but it's resolved after sending an email. They guide us and provide solution of our problem,

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. I already sent a mail to adobe@xvoucher.com. Hope the issue will be resolved.

Comment: This means we have to prepare for adobe cloud as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all certificates here:
[click here](https://solutionpartners.adobe.com/solution-partners/training_and_certification/certification.html#certification_exams)

Comment: I have checked the link but the code (AD0-E702) is not there. Any idea?

Comment: How much it is old?  I think Adobe has updated guides, you can email them and ask about this code.

Comment: I have already emailed them and got to know that the AD0-E702 Adobe Commerce Developer Professional was retired and it is replaced with AD0-E717 Adobe Commerce Developer Professional.

Comment: Great!.........

Comment: Yes..they have updated with AD0-E717 Adobe Commerce Developer Professional with cloud Add-on. You need to have some cloud knowledge also to pass this exam. You can check it here. https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7011797223105511424?updateEntityUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_feedUpdate%3A%28V2%2Curn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A7011797223105511424%29